# Podman unable to connect to containers/images

Tags: timeout, podman

I make an `podman run -d -name ...` command, and I take back this message

Error: initializing source docker://redis:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: i/o timeout

I use windows 10 for this.

I have try to connect the path from enviroment viriables, I have unistall and install podman from start. At podman Desktop everything looks good, but I have zero containers and zero images.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be 1 of several reasons.

- Have you checked that the podman machine is initialized?
- What image are you trying to use?
- Could you pass the complete command to see if it is being typed correctly?

Comment: I have the same issue. It might be connected that I had docker desktop install before hand. I uninstall it and the install podman. It is initializing correctly. 
When I try to pull sample image: podman run --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name httpd_container docker.io/library/httpd

I am getting following error:
Error: initializing source docker://httpd:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Strange, I just ran that command and it brings up and runs the container correctly.

Comment: I think is sth to do with my company firewall policy or mis configure tunelling that was blocking podman from connection to internet. Anyway I moved to rancher desktop which took care of it automatically.